# File API, web workers, and Chrome/Chromium

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web-worker, fileapi

The following minimal HTML file results in an error in the browser's console. `File` is undefined when accessed from a web worker in Chrome.

I am somewhat puzzled by this: it is working perfectly well with Firefox and I'd expect Chrome to have this already ironed out, at in a development version (the problem seems present in Chrome 22, 23, and 24).

Am I missing something, or is there a workaround to get it to work with Chrome (or may be even other browsers) ?

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
// File seems to be defined
var slice = File.prototype.webkitSlice;

window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
// File is not defined when creating the worker below
var blob = new Blob(["var slice = File.prototype.webkitSlice;"]);
var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

// Getting:
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined 
var worker = new Worker(blobURL);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `File` to `Blob`, your script works. `File` inherits from `Blob`.

```
var blob = new Blob(["var slice = Blob.prototype.webkitSlice;"]);
```

For anyone following: [crbug.com/147503](http://crbug.com/147503)

Comment: Nice (although now this seems to be causing trouble to Opera). PS: I filed that bug report.

Answer (score 0):

`WebkitSlice` is deprecated in chrome latest version so use `slice` instead of it. and use it

as ebidel stated

```
var blob = new Blob(["var slice = Blob.prototype.slice;"]);
```